# Datastore Admin Redirect loops

Tags: google-app-engine

I can't access the Datastore Admin tab due to a "This webpage has a redirect loop" error and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong or have set up wrong.

I have Datastore Admin Enabled in my web console.

I've added (although I don't know if this is even necessary):

```
builtins:
- datastore_admin: on
```

I've cleared cookies, etc.

Authentication Options is set to Google Accounts API

Has anyone else seen this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is being discussed here and I am going to answer it.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4233

First a question.  Which browser is this on?

I've had this problem on chrome and it's related to Chrome blocking third-party cookies, over-all a nice thing for it to do.  You can add an exception to your third-party cookie settings to make fix the problem.

You need to go to the Chrome settings page. You may need to expand an option called Show advanced settings...

Then look for:

- Privacy / Content settings...
- Cookies / Manage exceptions...

Then add an exception at the bottom of this list.  The exception should look like this:

https://ah-builtin-python-bundle-dot-latest-dot-[YOUR_APP_ID].appspot.com/_ah/datastore_admin/*

Comment: So Google's browser is failing on Google's own site? Nice. Thanks for the answer.